# What kind of traction does cells have in the Rails community?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells

I am commencing a Rails build and have been looking at [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) - seems like a powerful piece of kit. What kind of real traction does cells have in the community at large and is it worth implementing for a site that is likely to have a fairly complex view layer?

Comment: For those of us who might *not* be familiar with "Cells" it would be helpful if you could link to the project from w/in your question...

Comment: I did link it! https://github.com/apotonick/cells

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think the response you have received in 3 hours basically answers your question...

Comment: Indeed! Nada, zilch, tumbleweed.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Oh what a turnout! There is something similar boiling up in the Rails community now.
https://github.com/github/view_component

Answer (score 4):

Funny, read this to learn the contrary http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/fkjix/what_do_you_think_about_the_cells_gem/

:-D

Answer (score 3):

There was some discussion about it awhile back, but thats mostly cause the author of the library posted a series of articles about it on rubyflow. It is definately not one of those things everyone uses.

Personally, I don't buy the assertion that partials + helpers are bad, and I think cells is an overly complex solution to most scenarios. I would imagine it would have its place though.

Comment: Thanks, that was my feeling. Just thought I'd ping the community. Thanks guys.